# Crosstalk filtering of 2 DT tables with 2 filters

Tags: r, dt, flexdashboard, crosstalk

I am trying to replicate the functionality of an Excel pivot table using a Flexdashboard with crosstalk and DT.  I need to be able to show both a data table and a summary table, and be able to apply the same filters on both tables at the same time.

The example below works to filter using one field, "manufacturer".  What I can't seem to figure out is how to add another filter, like say "continent", to work on both tables.

````
---
title: "Filter 2 tables With Crosstalk"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
  vertical_layout: scroll
  theme: cosmo
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(crosstalk)

car_data <- "manufacturer,model,displ,year,cyl,trans,drv,cty,hwy,fl,class,continent
audi,a4,1.8,1999,4,auto,f,18,29,p,compact,europe
audi,a4,1.8,1999,4,manual,f,21,29,p,compact,europe
audi,a4,2,2008,4,manual,f,20,31,p,compact,europe
audi,a4,2,2008,4,auto,f,21,30,p,compact,europe
audi,a4,2.8,1999,6,auto,f,16,26,p,compact,europe
chevrolet,malibu,2.4,1999,4,auto,f,19,27,r,midsize,america
chevrolet,malibu,2.4,2008,4,auto,f,22,30,r,midsize,america
chevrolet,malibu,3.1,1999,6,auto,f,18,26,r,midsize,america
chevrolet,malibu,3.5,2008,6,auto,f,18,29,r,midsize,america
chevrolet,malibu,3.6,2008,6,auto,f,17,26,r,midsize,america
dodge,caravan 2wd,2.4,1999,4,auto,f,18,24,r,minivan,america
dodge,caravan 2wd,3,1999,6,auto,f,17,24,r,minivan,america
dodge,caravan 2wd,3.3,1999,6,auto,f,16,22,r,minivan,america
dodge,caravan 2wd,3.3,1999,6,auto,f,16,22,r,minivan,america
dodge,caravan 2wd,3.3,2008,6,auto,f,17,24,r,minivan,america"

# Create df1 & df2
mpg_cars <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = car_data)

summary_mpg <- mpg_cars %>% 
  group_by(continent,
           manufacturer) %>%
  summarize(cty = mean(cty),
            hwy = mean(hwy),
            models = n())
```

Row
------------------------

### Filters

```{r include=TRUE, message=FALSE}
############### This Works! #######################
sd1 <- SharedData$new(mpg_cars, 
                      ~manufacturer, 
                      group = "Manufacturer")

sd2 <- SharedData$new(summary_mpg, 
                      ~manufacturer, 
                      group = "Manufacturer")
# 
filter_select("manufacturer", 
              "Manufacturer:", 
              sd1, 
              ~manufacturer)
```

### Shared Summary

```{r include=TRUE, message=FALSE}
DT::datatable(sd2)
```


Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Shared data

```{r include=TRUE, message=FALSE}
DT::datatable(sd1)
```
````

I have tried the following, but it did not work right.

```
############## Do multiple fields work? #####################

# sd1 <- SharedData$new(mpg_cars, group = "individual")
# sd2 <- SharedData$new(summary_mpg, group = "individual")
# 
# filter_select(id = "group1",
#               sharedData = sd1,
#               group = ~manufacturer,
#               label = "Mfg. Filter")
# 
# filter_select(id = "group2",
#               sharedData = sd1,
#               group = ~continent,
#               label = "Cont. Filter")
```

Comment: According to `?SharedData` `In some cases, you will want to have multiple independent SharedData objects link up to form a single web of widgets that all share selection and filtering state; in those cases, you'll give those SharedData objects the same group name.`

Comment: Hi Akrun.  Yes, I saw that in the doc, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make that work.  If anyone has code that shows how this works, I would love to see it.  In my working example above, would this mean that I would add a group, say "continent" to each SharedData object, like this? `sd1 <- SharedData$new(mpg_cars, ~continent, group = "Continent")`